# Removing perl from ubuntu docker image cause pyodbc to fail

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pyodbc

Running into an expected issue trying to prepare an ubuntu 20.04 based image with python and pyodbc.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# install mssql odbc driver

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y curl gnupg build-essential

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev

# install python 3.7.9 from source

RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip

# clean up

# this does not work
RUN apt-get remove -y perl curl gnupg && apt-get autoremove -y

# this works
# RUN apt-get remove -y curl gnupg && apt-get autoremove -y

RUN pip3 install pyodbc
```

If perl is not removed, the installation of pyodbc is uneventful, but if perl is removed, the following error is displayed:

```
src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
```

As if the unixodbc-dev is also removed for some reason. Has anyone run into this before? If perl is required, wouldn't `apt-get` prevent it from being deleted? Or I need to install a different set of c-bindings to make this work.

Also running `apt-get install -f` after installing msodbcsql17 doesn't help either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unixodbc-dev` was installed as a transitive dependency and was automatically removed when no longer needed, i.e. after perl was removed.  You need to install it explicitly:

```
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
```

See the following bug report for details: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/441